# ruby redirect multiple processes output to log

Tags: ruby, multithreading, file-io

My ruby script should handle multiple external processes, so I was wondering how to redirect the output from different process to different log file(s). Also, as the external process takes quite a bit of time to complete, what is the best way of handling them in parallel?

As I am new to ruby I can show you an shell equivalent code:

```
LOGDIR="/tmp/test"
for host in $( h1 h2 h3 h4 ); do
  ( ssh root@${host} 'sh /tmp/scripttorun' >> ${LOGDIR}/${host}.log 2>&1 ) &
  sleep 5
done
wait #wait for all subprocesses to complete
```

Comment: Some clarification on the nature of these "external processes" would help. Are these command line processes? Are you calling rest urls?

Comment: yes, they are command line programs which will be executed on multiple systems using net/ssh.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine to use a very similar approach for redirecting your output to the log files, using either backticks or `%x` if you choose:

```
`cp -v some/file/that/does/not/exist some/file/name >> /path/to/stdout.log 2>>/path/to/stderr.log`
```

If you want to pass the values in variables, use:

```
`ssh root@#{host} 'sh /tmp/scripttorun' >> #{LOGDIR}/#{host}.log 2>&1`
```

This all assumes you're using SSH keys though. SSH won't make the connection without them, and instead will pause with a prompt to enter your password, causing your code to hang. You'll need to work around that situation using the Net::SSH gem programmatically.

To handle them in parallel, I'd recommend looking at [EventMachine](http://eventmachine.rubyforge.org) and [EM-SSH](https://github.com/simulacre/em-ssh).

Answer (score 0):

The code I came up with in Ruby is as follows:

```
@pids = []
hosts = %w(h1 h2 h3 h4)
hosts.each do |host|
  @pids << Kernel.fork { `ssh root@#{host} 'sh /tmp/test' >> #{LOGDIR}/#{host}.log 2>&1` }
end
@pids.each { |pid| Process.wait(pid) }
```

Please add if this implementation has some drawbacks.